# PHP stripslashes variable encoding from contact form

Tags: php, post, utf-8, stripslashes

In my PHP contact form script,

I'm using `_POST` to submit a PHP variable containing quotation marks that have to be escaped, and upon arrival, its value becomes the value of the `$formSubject` variable in the form, and has its slashes removed with `stripslashes`.

Here are excerpts from the form showing the `$formSubject` variable, as well as the headers.

```
<input type="text" name="formSubject" id="formSubject" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['formSubject']))  echo stripslashes($_POST['formSubject']);?>" />

if (($resp->is_valid) && (!isset($hasError))) {
  $emailTo = 'yourEmail@address.com';
  $subject = 'A new message from: ' . $formAuthor . ' | ' . $formSubject;
  $body = "Email: $formEmail \n\nContent: $formContent  \n\n$formAuthor";
  $headers = 'From: <'.$formEmail.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $formEmail . "\r\n" . 'Return-Path: ' . $formEmail;
```

Since I've started using `stripslashes` on the echoed variable, the subject is correct on the form's page, but once the email arrives, ASCII in subject is not parsing correctly.

```
THIS IS A \&#39;SUBJECT\&#39;
```

should be:

```
THIS IS A 'SUBJECT'
```

Is this a matter of declaring the correct encoding? This only happened when I started using `stripslashes` so does stripslashes disregard encoding? I read about an attribute to use on `<form>` for setting `UTF-8`, but that didn't work. Is there a fix specific to stripslashes, or is there an overall change I'd have to make for the script encoding?

Can anyone tell me what the issue is?

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: try html_entities_decode function.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php